# Python & MySQL - solution for storing lists in databases?

Tags: python, mysql, database

So I'm new to databases and stumped as to how to do something that seems fairly ubiquitous in websites: 
I have a database (working with Python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy), that currently is storing info about individual files(images), model looks something like:

```
class Storedfile(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    filename = db.Column(db.Text)
    filesize = db.Column(db.Integer)
    upload_time = db.Column(db.DateTime)
```

But what I want to do is be able to group these files if they are uploaded together into galleries. Up to 100 files can be uploaded at a time but the gallery could be any number of files 2-100. So first thing that comes to mind is having a gallery model(class?) that stores lists of images(which would be instances of the Storedfile class), but I know that storing lists in columns of relational databases pretty much defeats the purpose of relational databases, and even if you wanted to do this it requires hacky and cumbersome solutions. So basically, I need to store a list of images associated with a gallery,  of which could  consist of any number of entries between 2 and 100.   How could I go about doing this? Thank you.

Comment: The key word is "relational" database. You need a relationship between a Gallery model and your Storedfile

Comment: I actually do have an attribute of my Storedfile that could work, each file has a gallery_id, and all files of a gallery would have the same gallery_id. I was trying to sort galleries before by just querying Storedfile for all files with that ID, but I thought there might be a better solution.

Comment: How can I actually implement this?

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html

Answer (score 0):

Modify your StoredFile model so it has an index to the gallery (gallery_id for instance), modify the table as well.

Create a gallery table with an id field, and perhaps a name.